# Django: change media root for tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I am trying to write some tests for a Django application, involving file upload. For that, I want to change the `MEDIA_ROOT` temporarily to 'myproject/fixtures/test_media/'. For some reason it seems that this prevents Django to find the fixtures.

My test case looks like

```
from django.conf import settings

class TestMedia(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixtures/test_data.json']

    def setUp(self):
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT = ''.join(
            [settings.PROJECT_PATH, '/fixtures/test_media/'])

    def test_photo_size(self):
        pass # Actually do something with the media files
```

For some reason, Django cannot then load the fixtures, hence all tests fail with

> Problem installing fixture 'fixtures/test_data.json': Traceback (most recent call last)
>   ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You May want to have a look at https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/06/26/media-root-and-django-tests/

Comment: cant believe 9 years passed and only one upvote till now for a good question

Answer (score 3):

Have u tried to remove the setUp and see if the fixtures can be loaded?

Besides, I don't think you really need to change MEDIA_ROOT to test upload.  You can just remove those uploaded files in tearDown to revert everything.

Edit:

It seems that you're running your unit test in production environment.  Honestly, that's not a good idea.

But if u do have to do that, how about use another setting file? Like this:

```
from mysite.settings import *

MEDIA_ROOT = '/what_ever_you_like'
```

And run you test with an additional parameter:

```
./manage.py test --settings=mysite.settings_for_test
```

Comment: Yes, without the setUp the fixtures work fine. The problem happens when I change the MEDIA_ROOT. I do not see how MEDIA_ROOT should affect the fixtures, though.

Comment: As for the possibility of using the original MEDIA_ROOT, I cannot do this. I need to have already some media files for the tests, and I cannot hold them in the actual media directory.

Comment: The possibility of running the test with an additional parameter is interesting. Still I have no clue why changing the media root in the test breaks the fixtures.

Comment: Django has a settings override for this cases and others, is so usefull

Answer (score 3):

Not override in setUp, it is execute only before of run each test method of TestCase subclass, override it in module before all tests.

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.MEDIA_ROOT += 'test'
```

Comment: Also see https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/06/26/media-root-and-django-tests/

Answer (score 2):

You can override all the settings for tests. Its a more "Django" way of - the docs discourage directly altering `settings`. There is a section in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) about it.

```py
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, 'fixtures/test_media/'))
class TestMedia(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixtures/test_data.json']

    def setUp(self):
         # any other setup stuff you need
```

A little bit more about overriding settings. You can use a decorator for a whole test:

```py
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings


@override_settings(LOGIN_URL='/other/login/')
class LoginTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_login(self):
        response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/other/login/?next=/sekrit/')
```

or you can just override the setting for a portion of code:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class LoginTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_login(self):

        # First check for the default behavior
        response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/login/?next=/sekrit/')

        # Then override the LOGIN_URL setting
        with self.settings(LOGIN_URL='/other/login/'):
            response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
            self.assertRedirects(response, '/other/login/?next=/sekrit/')
```

Note the different syntax for the inline version. Examples are taken from the docs.

Comment: IMHO this should be the accept answer, since its versatility of cover more use cases

Comment: How would you deal with settings that are affected by the MEDIA_ROOT? Can they somehow be adjusted (without touching everyone of the individually ofc)? e.g. we have a special file in our media root indicating if cleanup is allowed here (for test stages) and in the test case the filepath to the special file also needs to change after we change MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: This sounds like a case for using Mock rather than physical files.